# How to implement inner content dependency property?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I'm trying to implement a usercontrol with dependency properties. Here is my question; i want to set a dependency property with layout child or children of my user control. Is it possible and how can it be done?

```
    <custom:myControl1>
        <Label>Controls</Label>
        <Label>I want</Label>
        <Label>to set</Label>
        <Label>as the dependency property</Label>
        <Button Content="Is it possible?" />
    </custom:myControl1>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, declare a `ContentControl` in the XAML of your `UserControl`.
Make it bind its `Content` property to a `DependencyProperty` on the code-behind of your `UserControl`.
Add the attribute: `[ContentProperty("Name_Of_Your_Dependency_Property")]` on top of your UserControl class.

Then you can do precisely as you did in your question. The attribute defines the default Dependency Property so that you dont have to specify `<custom:myControl1.MyDP>`.

Something like:

```
[ContentProperty("InnerContent")]
public class MyControl : UserControl
{
   #region InnerContent
        public FrameworkElement InnerContent
        {
            get { return (FrameworkElement)GetValue(InnerContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(InnerContentProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for InnerContent.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty InnerContentProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("InnerContent", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(MyControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
        #endregion
}

<UserControl ...>
   <ContentControl Content="{Binding InnerContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Can you do the same if inheriting from Control? I cannot make it work for some reason?

Comment: It is not working with a Grid? I tried FrameworkElement and UIElement as DP for the content.

Comment: Edit: It was a typo in the DP

Answer (score 0):

Working as expected.

1. Created a UserControl and added a ContentControl binding the DP. (Create DP as said in above solution in code behind.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfTry2.Controls.DummyContentControl"
... x:Name="dummyContent">
   <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding InnerContent, ElementName=dummyContent}"/>
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

2. Used the UserControl in Window

```
<controls:DummyContentControl>
            <controls:DummyContentControl.InnerContent>
                <Grid Background="Aqua" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock Text="InnerContent" FontSize="32"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </controls:DummyContentControl.InnerContent>
</controls:DummyContentControl>
```